# Add new record button not working

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Add New Record button on a form. Whenever it's clicked I get an error "You cannot go to that record"

I have what I thought was the same setup on another database and it works just fine.

Comment: Can you provide details of the OnClick Event?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your query is 'read only' and potentially contains joins.

Are you using access?  I made an assumption that you are.  Please provide details as that will help you get a better answer.

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html

Comment: Also checked your linked table manager - ensure it's how you expect it to be.